# centrepoint, starting and ending point of tangential fillet/arc between 2 lines

Tags: math, formula

What is the formula to calculate the centrepoint, starting and ending point of a tangential arc at a given radius between 2 lines Ax1,Ay1,Az1 : Ax2,Ay2,Az2 and Bx1,By1,Bz1 : Bx2,By2,Bz2.

The lines intersect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's [intersection point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316490/the-algorithm-to-find-the-point-of-intersection-of-two-3d-line-segment) is P, and unit direction vectors (`norm` in the code from above link) of A and B lines are **dA** and **dB** respectively. 
Then tangential points and arc center are (four solutions):

**T1** = **P** +- **dA** * R

**T2** = **P** +- **dB** * R

**C** = **T1** + **T2** - **P**